# Flutter Error: Put a TabBar in the middle of the app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I want to put a TabBer in the middle of the app but getting an error with TabBarView.
I want to put a TabBer in the middle of the app but getting an error with TabBarView.
I want to put a TabBer in the middle of the app but getting an error with TabBarView.
I want to put a TabBer in the middle of the app but getting an error with TabBarView.
[image]

This is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hospital/CartPage/pages/cartPage.dart';
import 'package:hospital/Drawer/dropdown_menu.dart';
import 'package:hospital/FloatingActionButton/ConsultWithDoctor/consult_with_doctor.dart';
import 'package:hospital/ProductDetailsPage/some_medicines.dart';
import 'package:hospital/ThirdSection/SubCategoryPage/DiseaseDetailsPage/disease_carousel.dart';
import 'package:hospital/constant.dart';

class DiseaseDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DiseaseDetailsPageState createState() => _DiseaseDetailsPageState();
}

class _DiseaseDetailsPageState extends State<DiseaseDetailsPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: kGreen,
          title: Text(
            "Details",
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
              // onPressed: () => print("open cart"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Cartpage()),
                );
              },
            ),
            DropDownMenu(),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: kGreen,
          onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ConsultWithDoctor())),
          tooltip: 'Consult With Doctor',
          child: Container(
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage(
                "assets/icons/cwd.png",
              ),
              color: Colors.white,
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Card(
                color: kLightGreen,
                elevation: 3.0,
                // margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                ),
                // child: Container(
                //   // color: Colors.green[50],
                //   height: 330,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0, top: 10),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                              "Malaria",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  // decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                                  fontSize: 32,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    // Carousel(),
                    DiseaseCarouselPage()
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              // ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Card(
                elevation: 3.0,
                // margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                ),
                color: kLightGreen,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "Plasmodium spread by mosquitoes",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          // decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                          fontSize: 32,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '''Malaria is a mosquito-borne infectious disease that affects humans and other animals. Malaria causes symptoms that typically include fever, tiredness, vomiting, and headaches. In severe cases, it can cause yellow skin, seizures, coma, or death.\nSymptoms usually begin ten to fifteen days after being bitten by an infected mosquito. If not properly treated, people may have recurrences of the disease months later.[2] In those who have recently survived an infection, reinfection usually causes milder symptoms.[1] This partial resistance disappears over months to years if the person has no continuing exposure to malaria.''',
                      style: kSubTitleStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.black87),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),

                    // the tab bar with Four items
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                      child: AppBar(
                        backgroundColor: kGreen,
                        bottom: TabBar(
                          labelColor: kGreen,
                          unselectedLabelColor: kWhite,
                          isScrollable: true,
                          indicator: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(10)),
                              color: kWhite),
                          tabs: [
                            Tab(
                              text: "All Things",
                              // icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              text: 'Disease Types',
                              // icon: Icon(
                              //   Icons.directions_car,
                              // ),
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              text: 'Home Remedies',
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              text: 'Medicine',
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    
                  ],
                ),
              ),
           ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every TabBar must have  TabView (what will be shown on clicking of each tabBar).

And Number of TabBar must be equal to the number of children In your TabView

[TabBar Cookbook Flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs) will help you more